# How can I scale down a website without changing every single font-size, image-size, button, etc

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a website for training purposes and just expanding my skill in general. I've got a fully fleshed out site, looks fantastic, however -- a few people have noted that it seems just a little too....big. Not sure how else to put it other than this: It looks like it's SUPPOSED to look like when the browser is at 80% zoom. But at 100% zoom it looks a little too big. Is there anyway to kind of just scale down the site as a whole?

I've tried using `transform: scale(x);` in the body but that is just absolutely terrible and not what I wanted, and I really don't know what to look for / what to use and how to use it to really tackle this problem.

And when I say that going through the website and manually resizing all the fonts, images, buttons, and literally anything else is NOT possible, I mean that it is seriously not possible with the time given to me to do.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, manipulating the browser zoom settings or scaling a page is not considered good practice. Even if it looks awesome on your end, it does not mean it will look as good to a customer. There are multiple window sizes and devices to take into consideration.

The recommended method is to make the appropriate changes to the layout and CSS.

However, I have added a hack below that will work for most browsers. I just want to make it clear that I do not recommend this approach.

```
html {
   zoom: 0.8;
   -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
   transform: scale(0.8);
}
```